# History of my book's bestseller ranking on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

Can I see the history of my book's ranking on the bestsellers list on Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

You might find a third party tool to do this:  https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-best-Amazon-rank-tracker

Comment: Thanks. It seems those programs only track starting from when you make the account?

Answer (score 0):

Nate's Digital Blog has an up-to-date list of Amazon Sales trackers. https://the-digital-reader.com/2018/05/15/nates-big-list-of-ebook-market-analytic-tools/ Highly recommended!